# responsively center an element in free lateral space

Tags: jquery, flexbox, css-position, center, fixed

I'd like to keep a fixed lateral ad box in the *horizontal middle* of the *free lateral* space at the right and at the left of the main content of my webpage, *responsively*, that is regardless of the screen size. This should work for big screens because in the small ones there is no problem.

You can see what I mean, on this my [website](https://thoughfuldigitalworld.000webhostapp.com/) amazon ad box at the left and the right are not **horizontally** centered (in the free space outside the main content) if you have a big screen.

The solution could be flexbox and property "justify-content: space-around;", which should do exactly what I want.

But I noticed today that the **flexbox** is **not compatible** with "**position: fixed**": not, at least with my purposes. I have made many attempts, according to StackOverflow and Reddit threads about "flex and fixed", to combine a) in parent container (body)

```
display:flex; justify-content: space-around;
```

b) and in the box

```
position:fixed;
```

but if I do so, the box goes at the center of the window (*over* the main content)
... Am I wrong?

Do you know if there is another way, different from flex+position:fixed (maybe a javascript/jquery?) so that the fixed box keeps both a middle horizontal position and a "fixed" position in the free lateral space?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @sergey kuznetsov in his comments, **sticky** is the answer, so I have found this solution

```
body {margin:0; display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: space-around;}  
#fixed, #fixedr {position: sticky; top: 10%; width: 120px; height: 400px; background: orange; color: white;}  
#main {max-width: 900px; margin-left: 1%; margin-right: 1%; padding: 1%;}
```

note that it is important add a) the **height** of lateral boxes and b) the **margin** of the central one, otherwise all can be wrong. And, as @sergey kuznetsov, very helpfully suggested in a comment, c) it is important to **wrap** the divs into a parent one, to avoid a weird "dance" of the divs if *directly* under body.

```css
p {text-align: justify;}
body {margin:0; display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: space-around;}
#fixed, #fixedr {position: sticky; top: 10%; width: 120px; height: 100px; background: orange; color: white;}
#main {max-width: 900px; margin-left: 1%; margin-right: 1%; padding: 1%;}
```

```html
<div id="fixed">
<p>some content</p>
</div>

<div id="main">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </p>
    <p>Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh. Aenean quam. In scelerisque sem at dolor. Maecenas mattis. Sed convallis tristique sem. Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa. Fusce ac turpis quis ligula lacinia aliquet. Mauris ipsum. Nulla metus metus, ullamcorper vel, tincidunt sed, euismod in, nibh. </p>
    <p>Quisque volutpat condimentum velit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam nec ante. Sed lacinia, urna non tincidunt mattis, tortor neque adipiscing diam, a cursus ipsum ante quis turpis. Nulla facilisi. Ut fringilla. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc feugiat mi a tellus consequat imperdiet. Vestibulum sapien. Proin quam. Etiam ultrices. Suspendisse in justo eu magna luctus suscipit. Sed lectus. </p>
    <p>Integer euismod lacus luctus magna. Quisque cursus, metus vitae pharetra auctor, sem massa mattis sem, at interdum magna augue eget diam. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi lacinia molestie dui. Praesent blandit dolor. Sed non quam. In vel mi sit amet augue congue elementum. Morbi in ipsum sit amet pede facilisis laoreet. Donec lacus nunc, viverra nec, blandit vel, egestas et, augue. Vestibulum tincidunt malesuada tellus. Ut ultrices ultrices enim. Curabitur sit amet mauris. Morbi in dui quis est pulvinar ullamcorper. </p>
    <p>Nulla facilisi. Integer lacinia sollicitudin massa. Cras metus. Sed aliquet risus a tortor. Integer id quam. Morbi mi. Quisque nisl felis, venenatis tristique, dignissim in, ultrices sit amet, augue. Proin sodales libero eget ante. Nulla quam. Aenean laoreet. Vestibulum nisi lectus, commodo ac, facilisis ac, ultricies eu, pede. </p>
    <p>Ut orci risus, accumsan porttitor, cursus quis, aliquet eget, justo. Sed pretium blandit orci. Ut eu diam at pede suscipit sodales. Aenean lectus elit, fermentum non, convallis id, sagittis at, neque. Nullam mauris orci, aliquet et, iaculis et, viverra vitae, ligula. Nulla ut felis in purus aliquam imperdiet. Maecenas aliquet mollis lectus. Vivamus consectetuer risus et tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. </p>
    <p>Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh. Aenean quam. </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </p>
    <p>Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh. Aenean quam. In scelerisque sem at dolor. Maecenas mattis. Sed convallis tristique sem. Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa. Fusce ac turpis quis ligula lacinia aliquet. Mauris ipsum. Nulla metus metus, ullamcorper vel, tincidunt sed, euismod in, nibh. </p>
    <p>Quisque volutpat condimentum velit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam nec ante. Sed lacinia, urna non tincidunt mattis, tortor neque adipiscing diam, a cursus ipsum ante quis turpis. Nulla facilisi. Ut fringilla. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc feugiat mi a tellus consequat imperdiet. Vestibulum sapien. Proin quam. Etiam ultrices. Suspendisse in justo eu magna luctus suscipit. Sed lectus. </p>
    <p>Integer euismod lacus luctus magna. Quisque cursus, metus vitae pharetra auctor, sem massa mattis sem, at interdum magna augue eget diam. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi lacinia molestie dui. Praesent blandit dolor. Sed non quam. In vel mi sit amet augue congue elementum. Morbi in ipsum sit amet pede facilisis laoreet. Donec lacus nunc, viverra nec, blandit vel, egestas et, augue. Vestibulum tincidunt malesuada tellus. Ut ultrices ultrices enim. Curabitur sit amet mauris. Morbi in dui quis est pulvinar ullamcorper. </p>
    <p>Nulla facilisi. Integer lacinia sollicitudin massa. Cras metus. Sed aliquet risus a tortor. Integer id quam. Morbi mi. Quisque nisl felis, venenatis tristique, dignissim in, ultrices sit amet, augue. Proin sodales libero eget ante. Nulla quam. Aenean laoreet. Vestibulum nisi lectus, commodo ac, facilisis ac, ultricies eu, pede. </p>
    <p>Ut orci risus, accumsan porttitor, cursus quis, aliquet eget, justo. Sed pretium blandit orci. Ut eu diam at pede suscipit sodales. Aenean lectus elit, fermentum non, convallis id, sagittis at, neque. Nullam mauris orci, aliquet et, iaculis et, viverra vitae, ligula. Nulla ut felis in purus aliquam imperdiet. Maecenas aliquet mollis lectus. Vivamus consectetuer risus et tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. </p>
    <p>Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh. Aenean quam. </p>    
</div>


<div id="fixedr">
<p>some content</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the location of your rules `webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);` and `filter: grayscale(100%);` in `body` tag. Remove this it rules from `body`, and add these rules to the `html` tag, like this:

```
html {
  webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

For better block centering, you need to set the rules `top: 45%;` in `#publatdx`, and `top: 45%;` in `#publatsx`, like this:

```
 #publatdx {
        position: fixed;
        top: 45%; /*add this it*/
        right: 1%;
        max-width: 120px;
        margin-left: 2px;
        text-align: left;
        border-radius: 3px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 7px white;
    }

    #publatsx {
        position: fixed;
        top: 45%; /*add this it*/
        left: 1%;
        width: 120px;
        margin-left: 2px;
        text-align: left;
        border-radius: 3px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 7px white;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Grey filter is only before the cookie consent. My problem is not center vertically (why "top: 45%"?), but responsively **horizontally** in the middle of the *free lateral space*.
I have added something above to clarify my need.

Comment: ideally you should wrap these three blocks in a container for better centering. The topmost block, which displays (#cookie-bar) the cookie confirmation, should be set to position sticks rather than position fixed.

Comment: sticky is not a replacement of fixed, for my purposes, at least: I need the box remains fixed, while the main content scrolls.

Comment: sticky will allow you to make this block slide all over the page. the point is that your block will not overlap the top banner of the central page.

Comment: you was right: sticky is the solution. You can see now how is changed my website, linked above. I had to do some others changes, however. Thanks

Comment: I advise you to wrap these blocks (`#publatsx`, `#container` and `#publatdx`) in a parent block and set `flex` rules. Everything will be centered and done.